# AJAX responseText is undefined after GET request to .php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, responsetext

I'm trying to pull a list of devices from a mySQL db, which I then format into an html select/option element in my .php and then I echo the string of html to insert into my main page, but it won't return the string I echo to the responseText.

Here's my .php:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "admin";
$dbname = "devices";
    //Connect to MySQL Server
$con=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT DISTINCT device_name FROM device_graphs";
$result=mysql_query($sql, $con);

$responsetxt="Hello all :)";
$counter=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $responsetxt .= "<option value=$counter>$row[0]</option>";
    $counter++;
}

echo $responsetxt;

?>
```

I'm trying to generate a dropdown list of device names based on the devices listed in my db.  When i open just the .php file in my browser it echoes correctly.

```
function deviceDropdown(monNum, insideHTML)
{
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible! 
try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        ajaxresponse = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        alert(ajaxresponse);
        deviceDropdown_pt2(monNum, ajaxresponse, insideHTML);
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "device_list.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

ajaxresponse is undefined everytime I try this; it just pops up 2 empty javascript alert boxes.  If I run just the .php in my browser I get the correct output echoed to my window, so I don't think it's a problem with the php unless there's a problem passing html via php through ajax.

Here's the rest of the dropdown code:

```
function deviceDropdown_pt2(monNum, ajaxresponse, insideHTML)
{
//Sets the action to occur when a selection is made in the device dropdown, 
//  in this case the properties dropdown menu
insideHTML=insideHTML + "<select onchange='propertiesDropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, " +  monNum + ")'>";  
insideHTML=insideHTML + "<option value=\"-1\">-Select a Device-</option>";
insideHTML = insideHTML + ajaxresponse; 
insideHTML=insideHTML + "</select>";
}
```

My main .js has the following defined `var iframe=document.getElementById("bdy");` and:

```
insideHTML="<table id=\"dashboard\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" border=\"0\">";
insideHTML=insideHTML + "<tr>";
insideHTML=insideHTML + "<td id=\"menu1\" width=\"800\">";
deviceDropdown("1", insideHTML);
insideHTML=insideHTML + "</td></tr>"; 
iframe.innerHTML=insideHTML;
```

Comment: This problem can be related with your ajaxRequest. Consider using some library like jQuery to easily and safely handle an ajax request.

Comment: For one, initialize your $responsetxt variable in your PHP by setting it to "" before anything is done.

Secondly, I know you can send HTML via an AJAX request so that is not the problem.

Comment: @JasonKaczmarsky Sorry, I do initialize it, I just forgot to paste it in here because I had been playing with it and initiliazed it to "Hello :)" to see if I could get nonHTML code to pass through. I've updated the code above to reflect this.

Comment: First variable within quote should be like; {$row[0]}. Not compulsory but advised.

Comment: Try alert(response.toString()) and see if it alerts an object.

Comment: Aha, it's because you have initialized var ajaxRequest inside a function rather than globally.  When onreadystatechange runs it doesn't have that variable in its scope.  Quick fix: remove the var ajaxRequest line.  Better fix:  pass ajaxRequest, monNum, insideHTML to a separate function that creates the .onreadystatechange handler.

Comment: @James ajaxRequest is used inside closure, so it's ok.

Comment: @Chelsi.Hohnbaum Your code works fine for me. Try Firebug to figure out what request is done by your browser. Is it the same URL that you opened manually?

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://jquery.com/

simple example for what you want to achieve:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

and all you have to do is include this in your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script
```